# JSON - Check if field exists by name

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, xpath

I have a field name stored in the database.
I would like to check if this field exists in my JSON in Angular 13 app.
In XML I would do this: `myXmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/My_RootNode/id")`
Is it possible with JSON?

Comment: share your JSON format , search key format

Comment: Is that code something you would put inside SQL? If so, please specify what DBMS you are using (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, etc)

Comment: @IMSoP Yes, it's coming from MSSQL

Comment: Where are you trying to do this check? In your angular app or in SQL Server using its JSON functions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `JSON_VALUE` directly in SQL Server.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE JSON_VALUE(YourJson, '$.My_RootNode.id') IS NOT NULL;
```

If the `id` property is actually an object or array (as opposed to scalar) then use `JSON_QUERY`

```sql
WHERE JSON_QUERY(YourJson, '$.My_RootNode.id') IS NOT NULL;
```

In SQL Server 2022 you can use `JSON_PATH_EXISTS` for both cases

```sql
WHERE JSON_PATH_EXISTS(YourJson, '$.My_RootNode.id') = 1;
```